# TWILIO:.NET Wrapper twilio.UpdateApplication

Tags: twilio

The code below keeps throwing error

```
    Dim twilio = New Twilio.TwilioRestClient(TwilioSID, TwilioToken)
    Dim options = New Twilio.ApplicationOptions()
    options.SmsFallbackUrl = txtTwilioSmsFallbackUrl.Text
    options.SmsUrl = txtTwilioSmsUrl.Text
    options.StatusCallback = txtTwilioStatusCallback.Text
    options.VoiceFallbackMethod = txtTwilioVoiceFallbackMethod.Text
    options.VoiceFallbackUrl = txtTwilioVoiceFallbackUrl.Text
    options.VoiceMethod = txtTwilioVoiceMethod.Text
    options.VoiceUrl = txtTwilioVoiceUrl.Text
    Dim result = twilio.UpdateApplication(PhoneSid, FriendlyName, options)
    If result.RestException IsNot Nothing Then
        If result.RestException.Message.Length > 0 Then
            ShowAlert(result.RestException.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//Applications/ASDFASDFASDFASFS.json was not found

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually using the wrong method. I was trying to update phone number and UpdateApplication is the wrong call. It has to be UpdateIncomingPhoneNumber method

Answer (score 1):

Twilo evangelist here.

Based in the URL thats being requested, it looks like possibly your TwilioSID variable is empty.  What I would expect to see if a URL that looks more like this:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/[YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID_HERE]/Applications/[YOUR_APPLICATION_SID].json
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could not agree more. However this is the wrapper API doing the URL creation not my code. How does my code have to be changed to make this work? The documentation here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications is what I am using as reference

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the TwilioSID variable has a value inside of your method?